# Error 500: closing file '/var/tmp/pve-reserved-ports.tmp.57406' failed - No space left on device [proxmox]

Tags: linux, proxmox

`Error 500: closing file '/var/tmp/pve-reserved-ports.tmp.57406' failed - No space left on device`
tell me how to fix it? it is on every virtual machine

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The error message indicates that the filesystem where `/var/tmp` resides has no space left, almost certainly due to a full partition on the physical disk device. In a default Proxmox install, this will be the root filesystem, but you can make sure by examining the output of:

```
df /var/tmp
```

Find some data on this filesystem that can be safely deleted. A good candidate might be any .iso files in `/var/lib/vz/template/iso` that were downloaded from the Internet. Delete the file or files and try opening the console again.

Comment: It might be useful to note that this error is about the *Proxmox host system*, not about any of the VMs.